# grep -P negative lookahead does not work

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find some lines on a file. I use a regular expresion and execute it with grep -P but I have an error.
The expression is :`[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2} =>.*@(?!gmail.com)`
I execute : `grep -oP "[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2} =>.*@(?!gmail.com)" /var/log/exim/main.log-prueba | sort | uniq | wc -l`
and I have this error: `-bash: !gmail.com: event not found`
Could you help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is expanding the arguments before passing them to grep. Either escape the `!` or use single quotes.

```
grep -oP '[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2} =>.*@(?!gmail.com)' /var/log/exim/main.log-prueba
```

or:

```
grep -oP "[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z0-9]{2} =>.*@(?\!gmail.com)" /var/log/exim/main.log-prueba
```